# Want to write regex in javascript which will check if all the mentioned chars exist at least ones

Tags: javascript, regex, string, javascript-objects, typescript2.0

I have string s and need to check if that string contains every single alphabet from a to z. What will the regex be to check this condition? where s can be very big string with multiple words separated with space.

ex:

```
pattern.test("zy aemnofgbc jkhil pqasdfrs tuvrhfwx")
```

should return true as it contains all a-z alphabets at least ones.

```
pattern.test("sdfasbcd effsdgh ijsfghtkl mnhtop qrsjht uvwmnmx yfdhjkd")
```

should return false as it doesn't have alphabet z.

Looking for optimum solution.

Comment: Lookahead to a, lookahead to b, lookahead to c,..., lookahead to z.  Long, but repetitive and easy.

Comment: I want optimum solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First solution with regex - removes all non-alphabetic characters, duplicates, and compares the string length with 26.

Second solution without regex, just checks is every alphabetic characters in string.

```js
const test1 = (str) => str.replace(/[^a-z]|(.)(?=.*\1)/gi, '').length === 26;

const test2 = (str) => [...`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`]
  .every(ch => str.includes(ch));


console.log(test1('zy aemnofgbc jkhil pqasdfrs tuvrhfwx'));
console.log(test1('y aemnofgbc jkhil pqasdfrs tuvrhfwx'));

console.log(test2('zy aemnofgbc jkhil pqasdfrs tuvrhfwx'));
console.log(test2('y aemnofgbc jkhil pqasdfrs tuvrhfwx'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Comment: Alexandr Belan can you explain regex (.)(?=.*\1)? I am having hard time understanding it, i realized that it removes duplicates but still checking on mdn webdocks.

Comment: @Kitty `[^a-z]` matches any non letter character, `(.)` captures a letter in group 1, `(?=.*\1)` checks if the same letter is somewhere else (on the right),  `i` modifier makes the pattern case-insensitive

Answer (score 2):

the easiest way is by extracting unique chars

```js
function testAlphabet(str) {
  var chars = str.replace(/[^a-z]/g).split(''); // it may need to convert to lowercase
  // remove duplicate
  chars = [...new Set(chars)];
  console.log(chars.join('').length == 26)
}

testAlphabet("zy aemnofgbc jkhil pqasdfrs tuvrhfwx")

testAlphabet("sdfasbcd effsdgh ijsfghtkl mnhtop qrsjht uvwmnmx yfdhjkd")
```

Comment: Suggest changing the replace from \s to [^a-z] to rid yourself of all non-alphas after you lowercase the string str.

Answer (score 0):

#### Is all a-z

```
function isAllaz() {
  let s = "zy aemnofgbc jkhil pqasdfrs tuvrhfwx";
  //console.log([...new Set(s.split("").filter(e => e.match(/[a-z]/)))].length==26);
  return [...new Set(s.split("").filter(e => e.match(/[a-z]/)))].length==26;
}
```

Comment: Probably want to lowercase the string in there to allow mixed case to be counted.

Comment: @chris, “ignore case” flag will be enough

Comment: but none of A-Z is in a-z. I thought that was part of the point... may be not?

Comment: Ignore case flag would not be enough, @nicael, because "a" and "A"  would not combine together in the set.  Also, hard to know whether OP really wants to count only lowercase or wants to treat "a" as equivalent to "A".

Comment: I assume that op meant a-z since it had a regex tag and had regex in the question but I could be wrong.  It's not a big deal either way and I don't mind being wrong.  I just enjoy working on the problems.